# Remove event before creating new one

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I use this function to create an event every time I open a popover:

```
var createCustomEvent = function() {
        var event; 
        if (document.createEvent) {
          event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
          event.initEvent("CUSTOM EVENT", true, true);
        } else {
          event = document.createEventObject();
          event.eventType = "CUSTOM EVENT";
        }
        event.eventName = "CUSTOM EVENT";
        if (document.createEvent) {
          popover.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
          popover.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
        }      
  };
```

In another script I do this to add an event listener to a node:

```
document.removeEventListener('CUSTOM EVENT', handler);
document.addEventListener('CUSTOM EVENT', handler);
```

now after some popover opening I have many `CUSTOM EVENT` created in `document` (I use `getEventListeners(document)` to test it).
I see many `CUSTOM EVENT` in console using `getEventListeners(document)` so I think they are event listeners, but I always remove `EventListener` before create new one so maybe the problem is that I have many *events* and not *event listeners*, I'm not sure about that.

How can I avoid this situation and create always only one `CUSTOM EVENT` using only JavaScript?

Comment: I'm confused, to you have multiple *events* or multiple *event handlers*? If you only want one event handler, bind it only once. Not sure, if that's related but `document.removeEventListener('CUSTOM EVENT');` is invalid. You have to pass a reference to the handler you want to remove as well.

Comment: I edited, it was my mistake but it's not a related problem. Btw I see many CUSTOM EVENT in console using `getEventListeners(document)` so they are _event listeners_, but as you see I always remove EventListener before create new one so maybe the problem is that I have many _events_ and not _event listeners_, I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

By [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener) to make `removeEventListener` work you have to provide the handler as well.

I'd suggest, in `createCustomEvent` to make an array of event types, as:

```
var createCustomEvent = function(elem, event, handler) {
    if (!elem.events)
         elem.events = [];

    if (!elem.events[event])
    {
         elem.events[event] = handler;

         [your handler attaching here]
    }
}
```

This way you'll be able to track the event and handlers attached to it; bear in mind that the above code tracks one event (as, you'll be able to attach only one event of given type).

Comment: thanks it is a good idea, but I could not apply it to my own case.

Comment: @Frank - if you could use jquery, it has a nice way of binding / unbinding events via `bind("click.CUSTOM_EVENT", function)` / `unbind("click.CUSTOM_EVENT")`. Doing this yourself in pure JS can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, Felix Kling was right, the problem was with:

```
document.removeEventListener(...);
```

the incorrect call was:

```
document.removeEventListener('CUSTOM EVENT');
```

the correct one is:

```
document.removeEventListener('CUSTOM EVENT', handler);
```